# capture image from webcam video (aforge)

Tags: vb.net

from [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559932/Fabrika-LAB-WebCam-Video)
vb project  i want to take screenshot and save it as image to my computer but i fail i try

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\Webcam")) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\Webcam")
    End If

    ' If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(VideoSourcePlayer1.Width, VideoSourcePlayer1.Height)
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(VideoSourcePlayer1.Width, VideoSourcePlayer1.Height)

    Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
    ' g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)
    g.Dispose()
    ' If (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\Images")) Then
    screenGrab.Save("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\Webcam" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    ' screenGrab.Save("testNyox.jpg")
    '  End If
    PictureBox1.Image = screenGrab
End Sub
```

but it capture live window  how to capture image from webcam use 
Aforge.net ? and from [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559932/Fabrika-LAB-WebCam-Video) how to capture image and save to my computer

Comment: screenGrab.Save is missing as backslash, but what is your actual problem? Expection, not building or what?

Comment: i want webcam capture image and save to directory from above project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually given in the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559932/Fabrika-LAB-WebCam-Video) that you gave. The Aforge `VideoSourcePlayer` control has an event that is triggered whenever a frame is ready, and passes the frame image to the event hanlder. So, just create a `Snap` button that when clicked sets a `Boolean` variable that indicates that it is time to take a snapshot. In the event handler, check the state of the variable, to determine whether to save the next frame image.

```
Private Sub SnapButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SnapButton.Click
    _takeSnapshot = True
End Sub

Private _takeSnapshot As Boolean

Private Sub VideoSourcePlayer1_NewFrame(sender As Object, ByRef image As Bitmap) Handles VideoSourcePlayer1.NewFrame
    If _takeSnapshot Then

        ' Put your image saving / processing code here.

        _takeSnapshot = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hi thanks but (' Put your image saving / processing code here) what's code ? please help

Comment: @monkey from Tanzania - The code that you have in your question for displaying and / or saving the bitmap image.

Comment: @monkey from Tanzania - Did this answer your question?